# Unity camera rendering

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem with a camera, I want to take a screenshot but I get this error:

> Flare renderer to update not found UnityEngine.Camera:Render()
>   c__Iterator4:MoveNext() (at
>   Assets/Scripts/ActionCam.cs:43)

My code:

```
public IEnumerator TakeScreenshot() {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        Camera camOV = _Camera;

        RenderTexture currentRT = RenderTexture.active;

        RenderTexture.active = camOV.targetTexture;
        camOV.Render(); // here is the problem...
        Texture2D imageOverview = new Texture2D(camOV.targetTexture.width, camOV.targetTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        imageOverview.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, camOV.targetTexture.width, camOV.targetTexture.height), 0, 0);
        imageOverview.Apply();

        RenderTexture.active = currentRT;

        byte[] bytes = imageOverview.EncodeToPNG();
        string path = ScreenShotName(Convert.ToInt32(imageOverview.width), Convert.ToInt32(imageOverview.height));

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
    }
```

There are my camera settings:

[image]

If I deactivate the "Flare Layer" I don't get this error, but my screenshots are more or less empty, only the skybox:

[image]

any idea?

Comment: is the `Camera camOV = _Camera` camera object being established in the script correctly? where is `_Camera` defined?

Comment: @Martin yes, also while debugging I can see the texture changing

Comment: Have you tried using [CaptureScreenshot](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.CaptureScreenshot.html) instead?

Comment: @Martin I cant use a different camera with this function

Comment: Looks to me like another unity3d internal bug. Otherwise I have no clue why it behaves like that.

Comment: Shot in the dark: Try your code in Update, instead of a coroutine. Also, are you copying the camera as advised in the documentation? http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.Render.html There also might be a timing problem, you can try other timings with Unity method calls like OnPostRender.

Comment: @Xarbrough I did this before... its not the problem.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski I believe this is a Unity Pro Feature...

Comment: Is your method in a monobehaviour class, and attached to the camera game object?

Answer (score 0):

I Use 3 types of screenshot in unity:

1. Application.CaptureScreenshot(ScreenSgotFile): Not using anymore because I prefer methods that stores the screenshots in memory. (I don't need the file because it is attached to a MailMessage and sended by an SmtpClient)
2. OnPostRender (it must be attached to a camera):

```
    void OnPostRender(){  
        Texture2D ScreenShot=new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);  
        RenderTexture.active=null;  
        ScreenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);  
        ScreenShot.Apply();  
        byte[] PngData=ScreenShot.EncodeToPNG();  
        PngStream = new MemoryStream(PngData);  
        //File.WriteAllBytes(FileShot, PngData);  
          
        // Preview on a sprite  
        Sprite Spr=Sprite.Create(ScreenShot, new Rect(0, 0, ScreenShot.width, ScreenShot.height),Vector2.zero, 100);  
        Preview.sprite=Spr;  
        Preview.gameObject.SetActive(true);  
    }
```

3. The same code but at the end of frame:

```
    void Update(){  
        ...  
        StartCoroutine(ScreenShotAtEndOfFrame());  
    }  
      
    public IEnumerator ScreenShotAtEndOfFrame(){  
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();  
              
        Texture2D ScreenShot=new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);  
        RenderTexture.active=null;
        ScreenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);  
        ScreenShot.Apply();  
        byte[] PngData=ScreenShot.EncodeToPNG();  
        PngStream = new MemoryStream(PngData);  
        //File.WriteAllBytes(FileShot, PngData);  
          
        // Preview on a sprite  
        Sprite Spr=Sprite.Create(ScreenShot, new Rect(0, 0, ScreenShot.width, ScreenShot.height),Vector2.zero, 100);  
        Preview.sprite=Spr;  
        Preview.gameObject.SetActive(true);  
    }
```